# How to limit the CPU usage of process?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-usage

I want to limit the CPU usage of process in a GPU Server. I find some ways, "`nice`" or "`cpulimit`". But they are not exactly what I want.
 
`cpulimit` allow a process to run as fast as it wants until it has exceeded a percentage after which it gets a SIGSTOP, followed by a sleep, and a SIGCONT.
But I don't want the process which exceeded a percentage to sleep. I just hope that it does not exceed a certain percentage. And keep it running in a normal way.

For example, when I run `cpulimit -p 1111 -l 30`, the terminal will be
`[1]+  Stopped`
This is not what I want.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible without sending a sleep to your program. But I don't think you should be worried about sleeps, because this is what UNIX does when another thread requests an access to the CPU.

If you see that you program is using 50% of a CPU core, it is **50% of the time**, because a CPU core can only do one or two threads at a time (depending of your configuration, *lscpu* to see on linux).

If you're building a app that consume always 100% of a core and never let a other process enter in, it may be possible, but you never know if your kernel will one time allow some CPU to another emergency program.

So my advice is to consider the fact that your app may be paused, because it may happen, and it is something you need obviously.

Hope I help you :) See ya !

Comment: Maybe this is the reason why I can not find a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way might be to design your own "shell-like" program which runs *another* process (or process group) and send it alternatively the `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` signals (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for more). For example, if you want some program to use no more than 50% of the cpu time, you might start it, let it run for 10 milliseconds, send it a `SIGSTOP`, sleep for 10 milliseconds, send it a `SIGCONT`, sleep for 10 milliseconds, send it a `SIGSTOP` and so forth.

A proof-of-concept of such a controlling program is my [half.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/half.c) utility (GPLv2+ licensed). BTW it does not show `Stopped` on the terminal (a message shown by your shell), because that `half` program does not stop itself (only some *child* process).

FWIW, I developed that program more than ten years ago, to be able to compile the Linux kernel on some overheating MSI S270 laptop

<sup>(the actual story is slightly more complex, and also involved too cheap RAM modules, which, when heated too much, worked wrong; I needed more than a year to realize that changing the RAM modules solved the overall hardware problem).</sup>